# How to empty an observable in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have created an observable, which is given below

```
  private permissionSubject = new Subject<any>();
  permissionObservable$ = this.permissionSubject.asObservable();


  constructor( public apiService: ApiService) { }

  updatePermissionsData(permissionData){
    this.permissionSubject.next(permissionData);
  }

  getPermissions(){
    return this.apiService.get('/getUserPrivileges')
    .map(data =>  data)
  }
```

Here what I am doing is, whenever I am getting the data, I am pushing the data to Observable

**Ex:** consider an observable -> [1, 2] and pushing 3 as it is new, data
now observable will become [1, 2, 3]

But I want to remove 1, 2 value from Observable before pushing 3 to it. How can I do that?

**Is Observable.empty() will do that, if it can, how can I update my code?**

I have seen many questions in stackoverflow, but nothing helped :-( that's why I am asking this question again...

**Updated code**

**Subscribing observable**

```
    checkPermissions() {
            this.checkPermService.permissionObservable$.subscribe(
    // Below one is getting executed for so many times whenever 
observable get new data (stream data)
              data => {
                  this.saveMenuItemsOnPermissions(data)
              }
            )
          }
```

Comment: Where are u pushing your data? add this code too..

Comment: Observables are not arrays. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @cgTag thank you for your reply. Yeah I know, Observable is stream of data, for the understanding purpose I explained my question like that. I want to delete the stream i.e., 1 and 2 from the Observable before doing someobservablename.next(3)...

Comment: It's a stream. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_data

Comment: @cgTag did you get me, that what I am trying to convey?

Comment: again, you have to invlude your code of context, from the code you've provided, there are no arrays and there is no push, and there is no persistent data here.

Comment: You can filter, mutate or switch streams. You can have replay or buffer streams. You can skip, take or repeat items.

Comment: @prakarsh gupta Please read my answer, I explain what your code does. If I miss something, maybe you should update your question.

Comment: @Mium Yeah, thank you for your answer, but If I do someobservable.subscribe() I will get 1, 2, 3. But I don't want 1 & 2. What I want is, Whenever observable gettting the new data, it should give me new data only ie., 3

Comment: Well in that case, the answer is : use operator `someObservable.skip(2).subscribe(...)` to skip the 2 first elements. I can give you a more appropriate answer if you post the part of the code where you subscribe the observables.

Comment: @Mium I've updated my answer, can you please check once.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding of how Observables work. You have no buffer/memory structure in your code.

**Your Code explained**

```
// instance of a subject.
// Subjects don't have memory!! The stream is pushed to subscribers once.
private permissionSubject = new Subject<any>();


// Here you make a restriction on `permissionObservable$`, so it listens, but doesn't publish
permissionObservable$ = this.permissionSubject.asObservable();


// constructor instanciates apiService
constructor( public apiService: ApiService) { }

// each time this function is called, permissionData is pushed through
// permissionObservable and permissionObservable$ subscribers.
updatePermissionsData(permissionData){
   this.permissionSubject.next(permissionData);
}

// calls a service and waits for subscription (http call I suppose) 
// the map function is useless BTW
getPermissions(){
  return this.apiService.get('/getUserPrivileges')
  .map(data =>  data)
}
```

**Observable.empty()**

> create an Observable that emits no items but terminates normally

`Observable.empty()` is not a method !! It is an observable whose purpose is to :

1. emit nothing
2. hang the stream

**Edit:**

If you just want to ignore the 2 first elements of an observable, you can use `skip` operator.

**Skip operator**:

> Skip allows you to ignore the first x emissions from the source.
>   Generally skip is used when you have an observable that always emits
>   certain values on subscription that you wish to ignore. Perhaps those
>   first few aren't needed or you are subscribing to a Replay or
>   BehaviorSubject and do not need to act on the initial values. Reach
>   for skip if you are only concerned about later emissions.

```
// Below one is getting executed for so many times whenever observable get new data (stream data)
checkPermissions() {
  this.checkPermService.permissionObservable$.skip(2)
     .subscribe( data => {
              this.saveMenuItemsOnPermissions(data)
      })
 }
```

There are 2 important points to bear in mind:

1. Subscription must occur **before** observable starts emitting
2. `checkPermissions` will ignore the 2 first received elements during subscription, but it will take all the following others.